# target="_blank" is not working for popup window in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

target="_blank" is not working for the modal popup window,link is opening in the same page and opup is getting close.

```
   <TermLink to="/legal/privacy-policy" target="_blank">
          Privacy Policy*
        </TermLink>
```

and the termlink are below:

```
 export const TermLink = styled(Link)`
  

font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.font.sansRegular};
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.color.core.blue};
`;
```

please let me know how I can fix this

Comment: where is `Link` defined?

Comment: @Samathingamajig updated whole code

Comment: The wall of text you provided was not helpful as it was just more instances of using `TermLink`. Where/how is `Link` defined/imported from a library?

Comment: no only css i pasted below export TermLink

Comment: Well you use `Link` in the definition of `TermLink`. You can't use a variable that's undefined, so how is `Link` itself bring imported or created by you?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by using next link:

```
 <Link href="/legal/rewards" passHref>
          <a target="_blank" className="TermLinkAction" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            Rewards Policy*
          </a>
        </Link>
```